# Can't access localhost in firefox

Tags: firefox

I am unable to load my local hosted sites in firefox, works perfectly fine on Chrome, and other sites work on Firefox. I don't have a firewall, didn't change any settings, and don't have anti-virus software. I am running OS.

Comment: check your proxy setting on firefox , and update to the latest version

Comment: I did that already and still no luck, it was working the other day, I made no changes, and then it stopped working.